# Make one window overlay all other windows on Kubuntu

Tags: command-line, gui

I want to overlay a terminal window over all other windows, even when I select another window, like it's always on my screen.
I'm on Kubuntu.

Comment: Look up "Always on Top". I'm not sure how to do it in KDE Plamsa (the DE for Kubuntu), but that is the typical name for what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kubuntu, open the "**Window Rules**" System Settings Module.

- Click "**New...**" to define a new rule.
- On the "**Window Matching**" tab, add a memorable description of the window rule you are setting up.
- For "**Window class (application)**", choose "**Exact Match**" and type `konsole` in the adjacent field.  If you are using a different terminal application, use the name of that application instead.
- On the "**Arrangement & Access**" tab, check "**Keep above**", in the drop down select "**Force**", and click the "**Yes**" radio button.
- Click "**OK**" at the bottom right to save the new rule.  Then click "**Apply**" to apply the new rule.

Now, `konsole` windows will appear over all other windows.  Feel free to experiment with other options in the Window Rules Module to tweak the behavior to your liking.

Comment: It's good, but is there a way to disable it and enable it whenever you want?

Comment: Hey, I found another way actually. Right click the title bar and click more options and you can show above others and it will do it for that specific window only! :D

Comment: That definitely seems like a better option if you only want to do it occasionally.

Comment: This is great if you want to layout your apps instantly especially if they autostart. Shows the true power of KDE.